# How to make various size images as input file for RNN or CNN in deep learning platform?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I want to use image files (About 10,000 images, in all different sizes) as input files to make image recognition program probably using CNN(or RNN).

I don't mind using any deep learning platform like Tensorflow, Caffe, Spark+Tensorflow etc. 
It seems like they all use fixed size like 256*256, but will there be any way that I can use image files with all different sizes?

If not, what will be the platform that is currently supporting biggest image pixel size as its input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea is to scale your images to the desired format. The idea of a neural network is to give a certain output for a certain input format. You can however change the size of that input to e.g. 1000x1000, but this will obviously lead to a slower learning process.

The 256x256 dimensions are probably the outcome of extensive research on the matter and giving the best results overall.